# как удалить в эмуляторе Android Studio всплывающее окно

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Как удалить в эмуляторе Android Studio всплывающее окно? Если нажать на **Wait**, то оно исчезает не надолго и потом опять появляется. Возможно ли это сделать как-то в настройках? Если у кого-то была такая проблема, подскажите. Скриншот прилагается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]